# PayPal API - Payouts - Handling of different Currencies

Tags: paypal-sandbox, currency

I am using PayPal Sandbox to test some scenarios for making payout.

I have successfully created Payout in the Test Accounts Currency GBP.  However in Some instances I wish to make payments out in EUR or USD?

Is this Possible?
Do I just need to add a balance in that currency - can this be done in the sandbox test accounts?

When I try to make a payout using an alternative currency that the Accounts registered currency I get a DENIED Error.

I only wish to make single payments to single users at any one time>  Should I be using a different API that will handle my requirements?